# Hover menu closes child when I try to move my mouse to it... Why? [JsFiddle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, hoverintent

The fiddle and the code speaks for themselves. I have a hover menu, and when the div opens and I try to move my mouse to it, it closes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle-products").hoverIntent(makeVisible,makeInvisible);
        }); // close document.ready
        function makeVisible() {
            $(".dropdown-menu.all-products-dropdown").fadeIn(100);
        }
        function makeInvisible() {
            $(".dropdown-menu.all-products-dropdown").fadeOut(100);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a role="button" class="dropdown-toggle-products">Hover me <b class="caret header"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu all-products-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Now try to hover me</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

## Fiddle Here

http://jsfiddle.net/dLKYh/1/

Comment: what actually you want? when mouse out from child then it should not hide right? or any thing else?

Answer (score 2):

Because the moment your cursor leaves the anchor, you're not hovering it anymore.

You should design the menu so that the "submenu" is inside of the parent. Don't put a `ul` inside an anchor though, make a div for better structure.

`<div><a></a><ul>...</ul>`

You can watch for `div:hover` and then display the sub ul. As long as your over any child of the div, the div won't close.

See this revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLKYh/3/

Answer (score 1):

You told it to do exactly that:

```
function makeInvisible() {
                   $(".dropdown-menu.all-products-dropdown").fadeOut(100);}
```

If you mouseout your $(".dropdown-toggle-products"), the ul will fade out.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this:

```
For the link [http://jsfiddle.net/dLKYh/1/][1]:

 $(".dropdown-toggle-products").hoverIntent(makeVisible,makeVisible);

For the link [http://jsfiddle.net/dLKYh/3/][2] :    

$(function(){
    $('div').hover(
        function(){
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    });
});
```